# Is there any real world phenomena that can be modeled approximately as Strict Sense Stationary process?

Tags: probability, stochastic-processes, stationary-processes

I recently read about the SSS processes. The definition is so strict in my view . I have think about that is there any real world phenomena that can be modeled as SSS process. I can find processes which are Weak Sense Stationary but I am not able to find some one to be at least approximately SSS (and imagine why they are?).

Answer (score 1):

Thermal noise in electrical circuits (caused by random motion of electrons
inside conductors) is commonly modeled as a strictly stationary Gaussian
process with power spectral density proportional to $|H(f)|^2$ where
$H(f)$ is the frequency response function of the (small-signal)
linearized model of the circuit.